# Creating a hierarchical 'DropDownList' in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, dropdown

I have to create a hierarchical `DropDownList` in ASP.NET. I have to implement something like the example I show below "through points."

1. The hierarchy maximum depth can be three. Example: Country-USA, State-Texas, City-Houston.
2. For a country other than the USA, I need to do a special search, and  because of this I don't believe that I can use `optgroup`.

**Example `DropDownList`:**

```
USA
     New York
     California
     Texas
          Houston    
Australia
New Zealand
```

**What I have tried:**

```xml
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2>
    Hierarichal Dropdown List
</h2>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Location"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search Result" />
</asp:Content>
```

Can you guys help me how to create this

Comment: Are you using mvc? then Ajax Call on change dropdown is the way.If you use traditional asp.net then use Cascaded Dropdownlist with Update Panel.

Comment: hi Parth I am using traditional asp,net and i need to do in a single Parent and child dropdownlist way not in cascaded dropdownlist

Comment: http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx this will help you.

Comment: Hi Parth i have to do in Treelevel hierarchy way only .Cascading dropdownlist i can't use here.

Comment: so you need 3 dropdowns each one is dependent on others.Say first dd will load all countries,then second one will load states based on selection result of first one and third dd will load with selection based on second dd?

Comment: Do you want to do this using postbacks (i.e. server side) or client side? It's a bit confusing, since you have used the `onselectedindexchanged` server side event, but tagged the question jQuery.

Comment: I have to create on onload in single dropdownlist in server side like tree view as you can see above example and ignore on selected index change its not required